# Objects set to nil after initial interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I am a pretty knowledgable iOS dev and I feel stupid for not being able to figure this out. I am currently working on a new app that upon launch checks for the last user, sets this property on the `AppDelegate` as well as the `users`'s `company` property. These items are stored in Core Data. On the `AppDelegate` I have overridden the setter for the `Company` property to make a network request as I need to perform a fetch every time this is set. The request goes through fine but when the call comes back (Im using AFNetworking 2) and I begin to parse the info and perform some actions on it, the `responseObject` is `nil`'d out. I feel like this should be pretty obvious but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. I have tried to assign the response to a new property and variable, with and without copying the actual object.

Comment: are you using cocoapods or submodules?

Comment: cocoapods for everything

Comment: and by seeing `nil` do you mean that you have a `NSLog` line that actually prints `nil` or is it just a breakpoint that you use to `po` and that shows up as `nil`?

Comment: breakpoint showing everything as `nil`

Comment: I just did a `NSLog` with the object and it is printing it out fine.

Comment: have you tried to add an `NSLog`? It might be compiler optimising the value out (pods have optimisation set to `-O0` fastest and smallest)

Comment: go to relevant cocoapods project and change relevant optimisation configuration to "none". Don't forget to switch it back after debugging (or run pod install again)

Comment: It is set to `none` currently. Weird, that it is doing it on this project only. I have this setup in use on multiple other projects. I suppose at least `NSLog` will work for now. If you have any other suggestions I would appreciate them, thanks.

Comment: I have seen the debugger lose its mind before and display information that is patently wrong. If a log statement shows the variable as valid and the debugger shows it as nil, it might be that the debugger is lying to you.

Comment: (And @SashZats 's suggestion of compiler optimizations that I just noticed is a good one. The cases I am referring to were in code that was compiled locally from source, with optimization turned off.)

Comment: Note that the debugger is famous for not showing the correct values.  Don't trust the debugger -- use NSLog or, in the console window, use `po`.